# Why do I get an error when using quarkus-amazon-lambda and quarkus-smallrye-openapi packages?

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, openapi, quarkus

I've been trying to generate some automated Open API specs for my quarkus lambdas. However, the `quarkus-amazon-lambda` and `quarkus-smallrye-openapi` packages do not play nicely with each other. When I try to run `mvn quarkus:dev` on a project that has both of those packages I get the error below. How do I get both packages to work together so I can generate openAPI schemas for my project?

In the larger architecture, I am using an API gateway backed by amazon lambdas in the method. I use quarkus on those lambdas. While I doubt I can have full routes for my lambdas because they are proxy lambdas and their paths are not defined in code, I would like to be able to generate OpenApi schemas for my java models that are defined in my project. If you can point me to a different package that has that ability, that would be an acceptable solution too.

Used this project to create a sample amazon lambda project https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda

**Error Message**

```
2022-03-30 11:54:13,318 WARN  [io.qua.ama.lam.run.AbstractLambdaPollLoop] (Lambda Thread (DEVELOPMENT)) Aborting lambda poll loop: ending dev/test mode
2022-03-30 11:54:13,331 ERROR [io.qua.run.StartupContext] (Lambda Thread (DEVELOPMENT)) Running a shutdown task failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to unregister all message consumer methods
    at io.quarkus.vertx.runtime.VertxRecorder.unregisterMessageConsumers(VertxRecorder.java:193)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.runtime.VertxRecorder$1.run(VertxRecorder.java:56)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.StartupContext.runAllInReverseOrder(StartupContext.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.StartupContext.close(StartupContext.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStop(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.stop(Application.java:203)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.stop(Application.java:155)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AbstractLambdaPollLoop$1.run(AbstractLambdaPollLoop.java:147)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:232)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.runtime.VertxRecorder.unregisterMessageConsumers(VertxRecorder.java:190)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. My cause was that quarkus-smallrye and the dev mode of quarkus-amazon-lambda both try to use port 8080.

After I added this to `application.properties

```
quarkus.http.port=7555
```

the application started up successfully. I hope that helps.